# Series of sharps (Diése) in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a crystal report document, where i made 4 summaries, 3 of them works fine but the 4th just displays a series of sharps (########).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will come when space is not sufficient for the field to display the number. Increase the size of the filed that displays the number.

Comment: it was the problem, thank you,, i tried to googled it, but it seems that you can't look for the string "#####" in google.